# Run php-cgi process

Tags: php, nginx

Today earlier my nginx server was 100% CPU usage, the process using all CPU was php-cgi.

I login and kill all php-cgi with this command.

```
kill -s 9 PID
```

Now after restarting my server is not working, I see the message "No input file specified.". I google this message, but nothing works, I suppose I have just to start php-cgi again, but can't find how start it.

UPDATE

If I run top command, I can see php-cgi running

```
1049 root      20   0  336m  20m  10m S  0.0  0.3   0:00.37 httpd                                                                                                                      
1051 apache    20   0  219m 5472  608 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.55 httpd                                                                                                                      
1080 root      20   0 20888 1180  592 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.02 crond                                                                                                                      
1182 root      20   0 19256  976  384 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 nginx                                                                                                                      
1183 nginx     20   0 19856 3176 1364 S  0.0  0.1   0:05.65 nginx                                                                                                                      
2326 apache    20   0  337m  13m 2512 S  0.0  0.2   0:02.07 httpd                                                                                                                      
2331 apache    20   0  337m  13m 2564 S  0.0  0.2   0:02.10 httpd                                                                                                                      
2696 root      20   0 96656 3820 2944 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.18 sshd                                                                                                                       
2701 root      20   0 12084 1696 1336 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.03 bash                                                                                                                       
2808 apache    20   0  337m  12m 1988 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.22 httpd                                                                                                                      
2864 root      20   0 12632 1228  948 R  0.0  0.0   0:00.29 top                                                                                                                        
2908 ulisses   20   0  183m  11m 6704 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.07 php-cgi
```

Run ps aux command, also show cgi-php

```
root      1049  0.0  0.3 344532 20700 ?        Ss   14:39   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    1051  0.0  0.0 224920  5472 ?        S    14:39   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
root      1080  0.0  0.0  20888  1180 ?        Ss   14:39   0:00 crond
root      1182  0.0  0.0  19256   976 ?        Ss   14:43   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
nginx     1183  0.0  0.0  19856  3176 ?        S    14:43   0:05 nginx: worker process                   
apache    2326  0.0  0.2 345492 13900 ?        S    16:56   0:02 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    2331  0.0  0.2 345480 13944 ?        S    16:57   0:02 /usr/sbin/httpd
root      2696  0.0  0.0  96656  3820 ?        Ss   17:41   0:00 sshd: root@pts/0 
root      2701  0.0  0.0  12084  1696 pts/0    Ss   17:42   0:00 -bash
apache    2808  0.0  0.2 345164 12848 ?        S    17:52   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
ulisses   2929  0.8  0.1 187732 11976 ?        S    18:06   0:00 /usr/bin/php-cgi -c /var/www/vhosts/teclasap.com.br/etc/php.ini
root      2932  0.0  0.0  10480   932 pts/0    R+   18:06   0:00 ps aux
```

Comment: You may want to look at [this article](http://nginxlibrary.com/resolving-no-input-file-specified-error/); it might address this particular issue for you! :)

Comment: Hi summea, i saw it, my [code]SCRIPT_FILENAME[/code] is set correct, all other things also. I think its not a configuration problem as it was running fine until I fisinh php-cgi process.

Answer (score 1):

You can kill all php-cgi by

```
sudo killall -9 php-cgi
```